# javascript slideshow shows all photos when site opens but not otherwise

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My JavaScript slideshow is acting a little wonky. When I load the page the slide show pictures are visible, but it shows **all** the photos in the slideshow.

After a couple of seconds, it does decompress to one photo showing, and works how it's supposed to, flipping through each one at a 5 second pace.

However, no matter what I do, it still shows all the pictures at the beginning, which defeats the point...

This is my HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
            <div style="display: inline-block; ">
                <img class="mySlides" src="../images/fullshot1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; ">
                <img class="mySlides2" src="../images/unnamed.jpg">
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; ">
                <img class="mySlides3" src="../images/fullshot2.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is my Jquery/JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 console.log( "document loaded" );

//declare section variables
var currentIndex = 0,
items = $('.container div'),
itemAmt = items.length;

//how to click and make it work
function cycleItems() {
 var item = $('.container div').eq(currentIndex);
  items.hide();
   item.css('display','inline-block');
}
//interval time
 var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
  currentIndex += 1;
   if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
   currentIndex = 0;
   }

cycleItems();
}, 3000);

//this closes the doc ready
});
```

Can anybody help me with this/has had this problem too? Thanks!

Comment: The items that are not active are not being hidden on initial load. They are only hidden when `cycleItems` runs for the first time, after the first `autoSlide` interval fires. Add another `cycleItems();` at the end of the `$(document).ready` function which should set everything up correctly on load.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Is this like while and do while loops where one runs on command once before trying it and the other just goes through?

Comment: Similar principle. `cycleItems` will only ever run for the first time after `3000ms` so the extra explicit call is necessary to fire it instantly.